# Open same url x number of times

Tags: javascript, shell

I need to do a relatively simple process.  I have a website containing my name.  I would like to open this website 25 times each time in a new tab.  Once the 25 pages are open, I would like to close the application (Mozilla FireFox).  I have done this in the past using a shell script, but it does not seem to want to operate properly.  I have firefox set up so that new windows are opened in a new tab.  I am also working in both a windows and mac environment so I was thinking that this would be best in Java Script or HTML but I am not very good in either, I do much more in vb applications.

Comment: Re: "I have done this in the past using a shell script, but it does not seem to want to operate properly": please post that script, and an explanation of what doesn't "operate properly" about it.

Comment: In windows it can be done easily using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mac, it's pretty simple to do in shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

# start firefox in background
firefox &

# retrieve its Process ID
fox_pid=$!

# open your URL in 25 tabs
for i in {1..25}
do
  firefox -new-tab www.google.com
done

# wait some time for the tabs to load (e.g., 30 sec)
sleep 30

# close firefox
kill -9 $fox_pid
```

In Windows, PowerShell allows sort of similar approach:

```
cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox'

$fox_app = Start-Process -passthru .\firefox.exe

foreach ($i in  1..25) {
  .\firefox.exe -new-tab www.google.com
}

sleep 30

Stop-Process  $fox_app.Id
```